# Price to rent ratio outside of major cities

Tags: united-states, home-ownership, rent, online-data-source, statistics

I'm interested in US price/rent ratios, such the list here: https://smartasset.com/mortgage/price-to-rent-ratio-in-us-cities

However, it seems like such statistics are always compiled by major city. I am interested what it looks like outside cities. For instance, county-level data would be enough resolution for me.

Do such statistics exist? Where can I find them? Is there a way to gather them easily myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Zillow has the data you are looking for - including county, city and ZIP Code. You will have to export to Excel though.

http://www.zillow.com/research/data/

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

## Zillow Research provides this information

[image]

If you export the county level data you will obtain a `.csv` in this format:

```
"RegionID","RegionName","State","Metro","StateCodeFIPS","MunicipalCodeFIPS","SizeRank","2010-10","2010-11","2010-12","2011-01","2011-02","2011-03","2011-04","2011-05","2011-06","2011-07","2011-08","2011-09","2011-10","2011-11","2011-12","2012-01","2012-02","2012-03","2012-04","2012-05","2012-06","2012-07","2012-08","2012-09","2012-10","2012-11","2012-12","2013-01","2013-02","2013-03","2013-04","2013-05","2013-06","2013-07","2013-08","2013-09","2013-10","2013-11","2013-12","2014-01","2014-02","2014-03","2014-04","2014-05","2014-06","2014-07","2014-08","2014-09","2014-10","2014-11","2014-12","2015-01","2015-02","2015-03","2015-04","2015-05","2015-06","2015-07","2015-08","2015-09","2015-10","2015-11","2015-12","2016-01","2016-02","2016-03"
3101,"Los Angeles","CA","Los Angeles-Long Beach-Anaheim, CA","06","037",1,15.26,15.19,15.16,15.07,14.93,14.86,14.81,14.7,14.58,14.46,14.38,14.31,14.29,14.35,14.42,14.43,14.33,14.3,14.34,14.36,14.44,14.51,14.61,14.71,14.85,14.98,15.04,15.23,15.38,15.57,15.81,16.06,16.34,16.55,16.73,16.87,16.98,17.14,17.3,17.47,17.59,17.7,17.77,17.97,17.92,17.72,17.59,17.49,17.36,17.31,17.23,17.17,17.17,17.18,17.23,17.22,17.13,17.19,17.19,17.27,17.32,17.32,17.4,17.43,17.43,17.27
```

There is a nice [Seeking Alpha article](http://seekingalpha.com/article/2945936-house-price-to-rent-ratios-in-major-u-s-markets) on this topic; it shows some analysis at the county level.